# Replace gender attribute values Male/Female to M/F in Rapidminer

Tags: rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner for data mining practice on training data. I have gender attribute with values "male" and "female" in it. I want to replace these values to M and F respectively.

what operator i can use to get this done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Map` operator is one option.